Why is audio generated by elevenlabs API in Python different from audio generated by website?
The code I will mention below produces very bad sound (output.mp3) as I tested on elevanlabs. What do you think is the reason for this? Is there a problem with the settings?
import absl.flags
import absl.app
import absl.logging
import google.generativeai as genai
import requests
import os
import pygame

# Disable unnecessary logs
absl.flags.FLAGS.stderrthreshold = "FATAL"

# Configure your API key
genai.configure(api_key="GEMİNİ_APİ") # Gemini API

# Initialize Pygame Mixer
pygame.mixer.init()

class Response:
    def text(self, prompt, question):
        """Sends the prompt and question to the Gemini API and returns the response in text format."""
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.question = question

        # Combine prompt and question
        full_question = f"{self.prompt}\n{self.question}"

        # Send a request to the Gemini API
        model = genai.GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-flash")
        self.response = model.generate_content(full_question)

    def text_response(self):
        # Display the response on the screen
        print(self.response.text)


def voice_response(self):
    url = "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/68gbrBPLYTEZzIIJ0apU"  # Voice model API
    querystring = {"optimize_streaming_latency":"2"}

    payload = {
        "text": self.response.text,
        "voice_settings": {
            "stability": 0.35,
            "similarity_boost": 0.85,
            "style": 0.55
        }
    }
    headers = {
        "xi-api-key": "ELEVENLABS_APİ_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response_voice = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    if response_voice.status_code == 200:
        with open("output.mp3", "wb") as file:
            file.write(response_voice.content)
        print("Audio successfully created and saved to 'output.mp3'.")

        # Play the audio file
        pygame.mixer.music.load("output.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

        # Wait until the audio playback is complete
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)

    else:
        print(f"Error: {response_voice.status_code} - {response_voice.text}")


# Main function
def main(argv):
    prompt = """You are a friendly, polite, and respectful male employee responsible for guiding patients to the correct department and floor in a hospital.
      You don't talk about things you don't know.
      I will give you information about the departments and floors in the hospital. You will answer the questions asked to you based on this information!
      If a patient has a problem, help them, approach them with good intentions, share your feelings with them, and give them moral support.

      Departments on the 1st floor: Anesthesiology and Reanimation, Appointment making, Brain and Neurosurgery, and Pediatric Surgery.
      Directions to the departments on the 1st floor:

      1. Anesthesiology and Reanimation: Go straight through door A1, it is the last door on the right.
      2. Appointment making: You will see it immediately to the right of the entrance.
      3. Brain and Neurosurgery: It is the 2nd door on the left from door A2.
      4. Neurosurgery: Go straight through door C1, it is the last right door on the 1st left.
      5. Pediatric Surgery: Go through C1 and it is the first door on the right.

      Based on this information, guide the people who come to you and always remember to not ask for anything more after your answer!
      Your answers should not be too short, at least 3 lines.

      """
    question = input("Your question: ")
    response = Response()
    response.text(prompt, question)
    response.voice_response()

# Main program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    absl.app.run(main)

It is an application that guides people who will work with artificial intelligence with the floor, area and similar information given in a hospital.
My only problem with the application right now is that, as I mentioned before, the sound is worse than the sound I tried from the elevenlabs in website.
You can even suggest new models and new settings if you want.
But please, the model must be Turkish or support its characters.
